# Can I use "adjournment" as antonym of "inauguration", is there a word for "last time use"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, word-usage, antonyms

I would like to know if there is an antonym to inauguration? By inauguration I mean "first time use of".

I googled this and [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/inauguration) provided me with "adjournment". Can I use it in the following sense?

> Fifteen years ago I was treated to the inaugural dream journey provided by my
> bed.
>  Tonight I sleep once again in my
> bed, it will be its adjournment. (last time used)

If this is correct can I then use "adjournal" as in "the adjournal dream journey"?

There is no more context than this really, I just stumbled upon this line of thought as I am moving abroad soon and it is the adjournment(?) for many of my belongings. So it is simply a question to better my English. :)

Comment: Why not simply "final"?

Comment: I would not use *adjourn* because adjourn has the implication that it is being stopped or postponed temporarily to be resumed at a different place or time.  You are not postponing the use of your bed, you are retiring it and so you are really talking about its final use before retirement.

Comment: "_Tonight I sleep once again in my bed, it will be its adjournment._" Is comma-spliced for no good reason. You might try this: "_After I sleep in my bed tonight, it will be {retired/decommissioned}._"

Comment: Thanks everyone for the insightful answers and comments! What an awesome Q&A community. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Decommissioning

and

> Retirement

are both suitable for some usages.  A "Closing Ceremony" is another.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm.  In my view English-speakers tend not to speak of inaugurating belongings, but of 'breaking them in' (I broke in a new pair of boots).  Inaugurations are for processes or roles or systems (the inauguration of the presidency, the policy, the new session of parliament).  I've searched and found references to inaugurations of buildings on Google, but that's about it as far as objects are concerned.  I'd be interested in other documented examples.

"Final use" can be used for the last time something is used.  "Retirement" can be used for the general process:  I retired a pair of shoes.  I retired my favourite sweater once it started to fall apart.

In the kind of sentence you supplied, I might simply use the following idiom:
"Tonight I sleep once again in my bed, but tomorrow I say goodbye to it."

When I moved back home, I "donated or "scattered" or "threw out" most of my belongings, I didn't adjourn them.  You can also "disseminate" things, but that's a bit pretentious.

Things whose use is being temporarily suspended can be described as "put into storage" or "put on hold" or "[mothballed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mothball)."